# How to make subfolder inside a folder

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save images to documents/images/AET/1.jpg but so far I was able to save to documents folder only.

I wrote code

```
 let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("images")

    try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: paths, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    fileManager.changeCurrentDirectoryPath(paths)

    let image = imagePic// UIImage(named: "apple.jpg")
    print(paths)


    let paths3 = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("/\(chkString!).jpg")
    print("chkString=\(chkString!)")


    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
        try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: paths3, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    }else{
        print("Already dictionary created.")
    }
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)


    // let pathToDatabase = paths3.appending("/\(chkString)")
    // let pathToDatabase =   paths3.appendingPathComponent("/\(chkString)")
    fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths3 as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    print("imagePath = \(paths3)")
```

Comment: can you add: you get error messages?

Comment: or what you get and what you expected? how did you check that it was not successful?

Comment: There is no error message. I was able to create at documents folder but I wanted to create folder inside folder so that wasn't achieved. I went to simulator documents folder and checked if it was created. imagePath = /Users/macXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXX-0EXXXXX/data/Containers/Data/Application/XXXX0-1XXX-4XX-BXXX-XXXX/Documents/AET 12.jpg. similarly I have a folder for /Users/macXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/XXXX-0‌​EXXXXX/data/Containe‌​rs/Data/Application/‌​XXXX0-1XXX-4XX-BXXX-‌​XXXX/Documents‌​/images but I wanted my AET.jpg to be inside images folder.

Comment: @rollingZtoned : Check the answer.

Comment: @rollingZtoned please edit your question and add this info to your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that you cannot create a directory passing a **file** path including the file name (`/../AET/1.jpg`). You need to specify a folder path without the file name.

Generally it's highly recommended to use the URL related API.

This example uses the URL related API, more descriptive variable names and the API of `Data` to write the image data to disk.

```
let chkString : String? = "AET"

let fileManager = FileManager.default

do {
    let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let imagesFolderURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("images/\(chkString!)")
    let imageURL = imagesFolderURL.appendingPathComponent("1.jpg")

    let image = imagePic// UIImage(named: "apple.jpg")

    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagesFolderURL.path){
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: imagesFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } else {
        print("Already dictionary created.")
    }
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)
    try imageData!.write(to: imageURL)

    print("imagePath =", imageURL.path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let path = "\(documentPath[0])/images/AET"
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } else {
        print("Directroy is already created")

    }
```

You can print the path and check through terminal it will give the directory that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default

let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
print(documentPath)

let imageFolder = documentPath.appending("/images/AET")

if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imageFolder) {
    do{
         try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: imageFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
     catch (let error){
           print("Failed to create Directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
     }
}
```

You should create subfolders like **"/images/AET"**.